# How to combine two string replace functions in one expression?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I would like to change some of my street labels like "**Musterstraße**" into "**Musterstr.**" or "**Muster Straße**" into "**Muster Str.**"

I already did that for the first case:

```
replace("name", 'straße', 'str.')
```

and for second case:

```
replace("name", 'Straße', 'Str.')
```

**But how do I combine both?**

I tryed different styles like:

```
replace("name", 'straße', 'str.') OR replace("name", 'straße', 'str.')

replace(replace("name", 'straße', 'str.')("name", 'straße', 'str.'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joseph's solution is well readable, I would recommend it, but to answer your original question:

```
replace(replace("name", 'straße', 'str.'), 'Straße', 'Str.')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this without having to use the **replace** function:

```
case 
when "name" LIKE 'strabe' then 'str.'
when "name" LIKE 'Strabe' then 'Str.'
end
```

This allows you to easily add more terms for any of your columns.

[image: Label expression]

[image: Labels]

Comment: Heads up to those trying this method: it seems to me that it only works for replacing entire strings, not parts of strings.  In the example given, it appears to work to replace "straße" with "str." if "straße" is the only text in the string; however if contained within "Musterstraße", it will not replace it with "Munsterstr."  (In my attempts to use this method to replace strings within longer strings, the result was that the data was deleted.)